# Lithium polymer battery charging and management

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-polymer

Can someone help me understand this type of lithium polymer battery charging and management.  I have the following battery https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/plug-1-5-3P-704260-704060_1600233788440.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normal_offer.d_title.5e6663bbOehjQ5

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I just plug this into a device without any battery management technology? As can be seen from the screen shot it says Discharge Cut-off Voltage is 3v so I'm deducting that its not going to damage the battery or set fire ect.
2. Do I recharge it with something like this?  Or if you know of a better device. https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B074Q6LCXF/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A25OOHM8C615QP&psc=1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circuitry you see at the output end of the battery:

[image]

is very likely a BMS -- battery management system -- which will enforce the charge cutoff voltage, discharge cutoff voltage and max discharge current specifications listed in the datasheet.

It might also enforce the max charge current, but I wouldn't count on it and it would be a good idea to make sure your charger limits this itself.

> Do I recharge it with something like this?

That charger would work as it can only charge at 0.6A. You would need to adapt the plug, however, since the battery has a 3-pin plug.

You can make a suitable charger from a very inexpensive TP4056 module which you can find on Amazon, Ebay, Aliexpress, etc. The instructions are readily available on the web, for instance at:

https://microcontrollerslab.com/tp4056-linear-lithium-ion-battery-charging-module/

The TP4056 will enforce a 1A charge current limit which is within the specs of your battery.